# Delete calendar event on Android (Samsung S-Planner)

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentresolver, calendarcontract

I am working with the native calendar, and I want to delete the events in native calendar. Provided that the event ID is known.

```
for (long eventID : eventIDList) {
     // delete from native calendar
     Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
     int isDeleted = mContentResolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null);
     Log.i("LOG", "Event deleted: " + String.valueOf(isDeleted));
 }
```

I have checked with the log. It returns "1" which means 1 row is deleted.
It works well on normal Android Device, and the record is deleted.

But the problem appears in Samsung's Android device (S-Planner). After the delete cmd run, `isDeleted` returns `1`. Sadly when I do a query through ContentResolver, the record supposed to be deleted still exists. `(In S-Planner, the deleted won't be shown, but it is meaningless for me in this project)`

Is there any workout to fix it?

** I have checked the delete cmd works fine on non-samsung devices, and `isDelete` returns `1` for all devices.

Thank you!!

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem